# Can this limit be proven to converge to the Logarithmic Integral?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Here's the limit:

$\displaystyle\lim_{k \rightarrow 1^+}\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\log_k x-\log_k\mu\rfloor}\frac{k^{j+\log_k\mu}}{j+\log_k\mu}$

where $\mu=1.45136380...$, [Soldners Constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Soldner_constant).

Empirical evidence suggests this is the Logarithmic Integral, $li(x)$, for $x>=\mu$.

How can this be proven?

Mathematica code:

```
f[n_, k_] := Sum[ k^(j + Log[k, 1.4513680])/(j + Log[k, 1.4513680]), {j, 0, Floor[Log[k, n] - Log[k, 1.4513680]]}]
```

Try f[100,.1.00001] or f[400,.1.00001] and it comes out to the Logarithmic Integral(n) +/- .0001

Further experimenting suggests the more general

$\displaystyle\lim_{k \rightarrow 1^+}\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\log_k x-\log_k y\rfloor}\frac{k^{j+\log_k y}}{j+\log_k y} = li(x)-li(y)$

if that's any help.

Comment: I'm a little confused by this notation.  Do you perhaps mean $$\int_\mu^{\log_k x} \frac{k^j}{j}\,dj$$ instead?

Comment: No, I definitely meant sum.  I did have a typo, though - I had meant log_k of mu.  Sorry about that.  And I forgot summation is customarily over integers - I'll try to rewrite the expression to respect that.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I don't think I'll be able to help with a proof but I can verify that numerical experiments agree with your result. Ignoring the floor function, Mathematica evaluates your sum as $$ \mu \Phi(k,1,\log_k \mu) - kx \Phi(k,1,1+\log_k \mu), $$ where $\Phi$ is the Lerch transcendent.